# ompl_ros_interface/tutorials: motion planning failed

Tags: ros, motion-planning, ompl-ros-interface, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I was trying the simulation example in pr2 robot of [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl_ros_interface/Tutorials/Calling%20the%20joint%20space%20planner) and when I enter the last command (rosrun example_ompl_tutorials ompl_joint_goal) the console answers "motion planning failed". In rxconsole it stated "Planning scene hasn't been set".

Anyone knows what happened? By the way I made sure to change all motion_planning_msgs for arm_navigation_msgs in the cpp file, since I'm using the electric version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33156/ompl_ros_interface/tutorials:-motion-planning-failed/) by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/11260/ompl-planning-scene-hasnt-been-set) may help.

---

Originally posted by [tor](https://answers.ros.org/users/1552/tor/) with karma: 277 on 2012-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0